# GWTP DOM.getelementbyid() and Document.get().getelementbyid() return null

Tags: dom, gwt, uibinder, gwtp

I added all the input element in uibinder and when I tried to access DOM.getElementById() in onbind() it returns null.

Tried to invoke DOM.getelementbyid() in OnReveal(), it returns element but, Textbox.wrap() throws

```
java.lang.AssertionError: A widget that has an existing paent widget may not be added to the detach     list
at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel.detachOnWindowClose(RootPanel.java:136)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.Textbox.wrap(Textbox.java:69).
```

But, nothing helps. Please help me to solve this problem. What went wrong? NO JSNI

Thanks,
Bennet.

Answer (score 0):

`DOM.getElementById` can be used only if the requested widget is actually attached to the `DOM`. In this case it might not be getting attached to the `DOM`. To do this call you need to call the method from `onLoad()`

Docs :

```
protected void onLoad()
This method is called immediately after a widget becomes attached to the browser's document.
```

Sample :

```
@Override
void onLoad()
{
    DOM.getElementById("id");
}
```